# How can I condense an array of numbers to a sequential series of numbers without losing their place?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Say I have an array like this:

```
[34, 55, 12, 66, 2, 43, 230, 67]
```

Now, if we sorted this array in ascending order, each element would have a new index (starting at index 0).

Now, what I want is to **replace** every element **with that index + 1** but **keep** the order of elements as it is.

Desired output would be this:

```
[3, 5, 2, 6, 1, 4, 8, 7]
```

I am restricted to Javascript and jQuery. How can I achieve that?

The logic behind 34 to 3 is that if you were to order the first array, you would get this

```
[2,12,34,43,55,66,67,230]
```

And with that - you can see that 34 is the 3rd item in that new array. so its new value should be reset to 3.

Comment: What's the logic behind converting `34` to `3` and `230` to `8`?

Comment: ...and what have you tried? What does your code look like? If you haven't tried anything, delete the question, make an attempt, and post a question if you have a specific problem.

Comment: I think he wants to sort the array and then replace the values with where each number would be in the array (1 indexed, not 0 indexed) when sorted.

Comment: what do you mean by condense?

Comment: The first array represents an array of unknown integers coming through a database feed. I need to normalize the array and use clean integers starting at 1 for further processing.

Comment: OK I get what you are asking now but you have so many votes for close and down votes that I recommend closing this question and try to re ask it with more clarity.

Comment: also there is a similar question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13368046/how-to-normalize-a-list-of-positive-numbers-in-javascript

Comment: The initial array comes from a list of <li> elements that cannot change order and have a special number assigned to them (value of the first array). Without reordering the list - I need to adjust the values to use only 1 through the max number of <li> elements. I have tried some logic to do this, but its not cutting it.

Comment: @PraveenKumar - the logic behind 34 to 3 is that if you were to order the first array, you would get this [2,12,34,43,55,66,67,230]. And with that - you can see that 34 is the 3rd item in that new array. so its new value should be reset to 3.

Comment: Again: Fine. You know what you need to do. What part of doing it are you having trouble with?

Comment: @user1882476 - please add this last comment to your question itself using the "edit" link so that people reading your question will understand what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could sort and filter duplicates out from the original array:

```js
var input = [34, 55, 12, 66, 2, 43, 230, 67];
var sortedAndFiltered = input.concat().sort(function(a, b) {
  return a - b;
}).filter(function(elem, index, self) {
  return index == self.indexOf(elem);
});

var result = [];
for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
  result.push(sortedAndFiltered.indexOf(input[i]) + 1);
}

alert(JSON.stringify(result));
// at this point the result variable will contain [3, 5, 2, 6, 1, 4, 8, 7]
```

We start by cloning the original array to avoid the `sort` method modifying it in place using the `concat` method. Then we filter duplicate elements from the resulting array. finally we loop through the elements of the original array and find their index in the sorted and filtered array.

Comment: You can do this without the n-squared second pass by transforming the original array into an array of objects with the original value and the index, then sort the objects, then extract the indexes.